# reducer return the state, but component getDerivedStateFromProps not called

Tags: react-native, reducers

today, I handle the error situation, when return error many times, the component getDerivedStateFromProps is not called, but the reducer is return state. what is it the reason?

```
 //here is the reducer error code, I use the console.log("the reducer"), find here return 
 //data
 case ERROR:
                {
                    console.log("the error state reducer returns")
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        isSuccess:false,
                        error:"load data info"
                    };
                }
                break;
```